# Add python script to CMakeLists.txt

Tags: python, cmake

I've to use 1 command :
**python** <somepythonscript.py> <input_file_path> **>** <output_file_path> 
 somepythonscript.py => It's a python script which takes a file as an input, processes it & generates an output file. 
 Now, I've to add this command into my CMakeLists.txt so that whenever I make, this script will be invoked via command & I can get the generated output file also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`FindPython`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html) module in combination with [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html)

```
find_package(Python REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT <output_path>
    COMMAND ${Python_EXECUTABLE} <somepythonscript.py> <input_file_path> <output_file_path>
    DEPENDS <somepythonscript.py> <input_file_path>
)
```

For the file to be generated though, you need to add it as dependency somewhere, e.g. by listing it as source of a target.

If you are sure the file doesn't need to be regenerated, you can use `execute_process` instead of `add_custom_command`

Comment: Output file needs to be regenerated